# How to get value from Python table that will be interpolate between columns and rows?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, interpolation

I have got table (DataFrame) created in Pandas. It is 2D table with integers as column index and integer as row index (it is `position x` and `position y`).
I know how to get value that is in "cell" of that table using indexes, but I would like to get value "from between" columns and rows that will be linearly interpolated.

Preferably, I would like to do this for large number of x,y  that are kept in two tables `Position_x(m x n)`, `Position_y(m x n)` and put results to table `Results(m x n)`

https://i.stack.imgur.com/utv03.png

Here is example of such procedure in Excel:
https://superuser.com/questions/625154/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-interpolate-and-lookup-in-an-x-y-table-in-excel

Thanks
Szymon

Comment: Uhm, Sample I/O?

Comment: your link is missing

Comment: I've added link with example. Maybe I will clarify why I need such a table. I have got flat specimen (plate) and I've measured it thickness in multiple points. Results are gathered in table where indexes are position and value in table is thickness. I would like to get thickness from that table but not only from  points where it was measured, I would like to be able to take thickness between points of measurements by interpolation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found something that works in 90%, however, it has two disadvantages: 
1) index and columns need to be strictly increasing, 
2) for a set of n input pairs it plots n x n result array instead of just n results (for example below for 3 pairs of input points I need only 3 resulting values, using that code I will get 9 values as all combination of input points).

Here is what I've found:

```
import scipy
import scipy.interpolate
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x=np.array([0,10,25,60,100])       #Index
y=np.array([1000,1200,1400,1600])  #Column

data=np.array([[60,54,33,0],
              [50,46,10,0],
              [42,32,5,0],
              [30,30,2,0],
              [10,10,0,0]])

Table_to_Interpolate=pd.DataFrame(data,index=x,columns=y)
sp=scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x,y,data, kx=1, ky=1, s=0)
scipy.interpolate.RectBivariateSpline(x,y,data, kx=1, ky=1, s=0)
Input_Xs=12, 44, 69
Input_Ys=1150, 1326, 1416

Results=pd.DataFrame(sp(Input_Xs, Input_Ys), index=Input_Xs, columns=Input_Ys,)
```

It's not perfect, but it's the best I could find.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question:

you can start by using [pandas.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.melt.html) to convert the multi-column-result table to a one-column-result table.

Then, you can use [ben-t great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53873198/9857220) to interpolate.

Hope I helped.

Comment: It's not exactly what I was looking for. I need to work on 2D table and get results from it. From table I can get result only for specific column and row and I would like to interpolate result from anywhere "between" rows and columns. Here is example how to do this in Excel: https://superuser.com/questions/625154/what-is-the-simplest-way-to-interpolate-and-lookup-in-an-x-y-table-in-excel